# Average value of objects in array in Python with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to know the average value of values contained in an object of my JSON file. I looped trough the array to retrieve values then I tried to calculate the average value with NumPy

Sample of my JSON:

```
{
    "gm_url": "https://www.url.com/",
    "results": [
        {
            "marque": "Alfa",
            "sold": true
            "price_int_eu": 49280
        },
        {
            "marque": "Alfa",
            "sold": true,
            "price_int_eu": 46000
        }
    ]
}
```

How to retrieve the average value of all "price_int_eu" and add a line after "gm_url" ?

My guess:

```
    for i in data:
        results = i["results"]

        if not results == []:
            for x in results:
                issold = x["sold"]
                priceinteu = x["price_int_eu"]

                if priceinteu is not None:
                    i["mean"] = np.mean(priceinteu)
                    print(i["mean"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put all the prices into a single list (or some other array-like object) to use `np.mean`.

```
for i in data:
    results = i["results"]

    if not results == []:
        prices = [x["price_int_eu"] for x in results]
        prices = [x for x in prices if x is not None]
        i["mean"] = np.mean(prices)
```

Notice that the next-to-last line only works if you explicitly have something like

```
{
    "marque": "Alfa",
    "sold": false,
    "price_int_eu": null
}
```

in your json. If the price is just missing, you need to change `x["price_int_eu"]` to `x.get("price_int_eu")` for it to work.

Edit: To deal with the case of non-empty `results` but no actual prices:

```
for i in data:
    results = i["results"]

    prices = [x["price_int_eu"] for x in results]
    prices = [x for x in prices if x is not None]
    if not prices == []:
        i["mean"] = np.mean(prices)
    else: i["mean"] = None
```

Comment: Wonderful ! But if I have only one "price_int_eu": null in an object, how to have a "mean": null and not an error (Nan) ?